# update a web part property using powershell

Tags: sharepoint-server, powershell

I have multiple page containing web parts,  I want to set a specific property, like Target Audiences, using powershell.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using below code

```
 $List = $context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("ListName")
        $context.Load($List)
        $context.ExecuteQuery()


        $Pages = $List.RootFolder.Files
        $context.Load($Pages)
        $context.ExecuteQuery()

        $Page = $Pages | Where {$_.Name -eq "ViewName"}
        $context.Load($Page)
        $context.ExecuteQuery()


        $WPM       = $Page.GetLimitedWebPartManager("Shared")
        $context.Load($WPM)
        $context.ExecuteQuery()

        $WebParts = $WPM.WebParts
        $context.Load($WebParts)
        $context.ExecuteQuery()

        $WebPart = $WebParts[0]
        $context.Load($WebPart)
        $context.ExecuteQuery()

        $WebPart.WebPart.Properties["AuthorizationFilter"] = "My Group"

        $WebPart.SaveWebPartChanges();
        $context.Load($WebPart);
        $context.ExecuteQuery();
```

Ref[Click Here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/c3c78200-1649-4545-849e-b76689d38dfc/set-target-audience-for-list-view-web-part-using-powershell-csom?forum=sharepointgeneral)